# How to deploy Quasar project with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, quasar-framework, quasar

I need to deploy a Quasar spa app to Azure using devops.

I get an error on build step. I created npm job with build command "quasar build".
But npm runs "npm quasar build".

What is the right way to deploy quasar prosjects on azure?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please install `Quasar CLI` and then run `quasar build`:

```yaml
- script: |
    npm install -g @quasar/cli
    npm install
    quasar build
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: 'install Quasar CLI and build app'
```

If you use YAML pipeline please just copy paste this. If you use classic pipeline please add powershell step:

[image: Powershell step]

Please check your working directory to be sure that you are in your root folder.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Could you please explain where should I place these commands? Is it two different steps in the pipeline? Or how do you organize the build process? Where do you put this script? I am quite newbie with Azure DevOps. :)

Comment: Thank you!!! You saved my day! Everything worked as you described. You just needed to add "sudo " forward "npm install -g @quasar/cli" :)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :)

Comment: Another thing to check is that you've run  `npm install` somewhere in the pipeline.  This tripped me up for a few hours while pursuing the above solution.  Also, note that Azure Pipeline logging can be out of order, which is, ... disconcerting.